# R Shiny : render_gt() slow to output a gt_table ( that is already calculated)

Tags: r, shiny, render, gt

I have troubles with render_gt table, it make a long time to show a gt table in my shiny app.

To see if the problem was the creation of the gt_table, I have created the tables and stoked it in a list. So the table is ready and no other calculation is needed by the app.

There is problem with render_gt() ? how do i can improve performances ?

Thanks fo your help !

Comment: Please provide us with an example.

Comment: @TrueCactus don't have a solution for you, but have noticed the same issue